# Solving a Cauchy problem related to the pendulum

Tags: differential-equations, physics

One end of a thread of length l = 1m is fixed, and a body of m = 1 kg is attached to the other end. The body is displaced counterclockwise by 30 degrees and then released. Plot the resulting  Phi(t) function on the interval t=[0,10], then create an animation in which you animate the time on the interval t=[0,10] and in which a pendulum moves according to Phi(t) function. The solution requires a numerical Cauchy problem solution.

Here is my take on it:

```
l = 1;
m = 1;
fi0 = Pi/6;
g = 9.81;

pendulum[fi_] := {Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[fi - Pi/2], 
      Sin[fi - Pi/2]}}], {Red, 
    Disk[{Cos[fi - Pi/2], Sin[fi - Pi/2]}, 0.1]}};

inga = NDSolveValue[{fi''[t] == (-g/l)*Sin[fi[t]], fi[0] == fi0, 
   fi'[0] == 0}, fi, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[{t, inga[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Animate[Show[ParametricPlot[{t, inga[t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
  Graphics[pendulum[t]]], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking if your solution is correct? The animation does not seem to be, as you probably want to draw ``Graphics[pendulum[inga[t]]]``.

Comment: I don't know if my solution is correct and i think that the animation has something wrong in it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

code

```
Manipulate[
 solveAgain[] := Module[{g = 9.81,u,t},
   currentTime = 0;
   sol = NDSolveValue[{u''[t] == (-g/len)*Sin[u[t]], 
      u[0] == u0 Degree, u'[0] == ud0}, u, {t, 0, maxTime}];
   ];
 
 Module[{pendulum, output},
  pendulum[u_] := {Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[u - Pi/2], Sin[u - Pi/2]}}], {Red, 
     Disk[{Cos[u - Pi/2], Sin[u - Pi/2]}, 0.1]}};
  Which[state == "reset",currentTime = 0; solveAgain[]
   , state == "run", tick = Not[tick];
   If[currentTime + 0.1 > maxTime,
    state = "stop",
    currentTime += 0.1
    ]
   , state == "stop",
   Nothing[]
   ];
  output = Graphics[pendulum[sol[currentTime]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    Axes -> True];
  Grid[{{Row[{"Time = ", NumberForm[currentTime, {2, 2}]}]},
    {output}}]
  ]
 ,
 Grid[{{"Length", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[len, {len = #; solveAgain[]; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 
      10, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[len]},
   {"mass", Manipulator[
     Dynamic[m, {m = #; solveAgain[]; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 
      10, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[m]},
   {"Initial angle (degree)", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[u0, {u0 = #; solveAgain[]; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 90, 
      1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[u0]},
   {"Initial speed)", 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[ud0, {ud0 = #; solveAgain[]; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 
      10, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[ud0]},
   {"Max animation time", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[maxTime, {maxTime = #; solveAgain[]; 
        tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 10, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny], 
    Dynamic[maxTime]}
   }]
 ,
 Grid[{{Button["Run", {state = "run"; tick = Not[tick]}],
    Button["Stop", {state = "stop"; tick = Not[tick]}],
    Button["Reset", {state = "reset"; tick = Not[tick]}]}}, 
  Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center
  ],
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{state, "reset"}, None},
 {{currentTime, 0}, None},
 {{sol, 0}, None},
 {{len, 5}, None},
 {{m, 5}, None},
 {{u0, 30}, None},
 {{ud0, 1}, None},
 {{maxTime, 5}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick, state}
 ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Animate[Graphics[pendulum[inga[t]] , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]